# Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5' is denied

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, devops

I'm trying to execute via PowerShell Admin a azure cli command to publish:

```
 az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/<ORG NAME> --feed <FEED NAME> --name <ARTIFACT NAME> --version 1.0.0 --description "Add description" --path .
```

and this is the error:

```
    az : Encountered an unexpected error.
At line:1 char:1
+ az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Encountered an unexpected error.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5' is denied.
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateRelativeDirectoryHandle(ReadOnlySpan`1 
relativePath, String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.GlobFactory.Init(String sourceDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.GlobFactory.PerformGlobbing(String sourceDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.GetSegmentedPagesFromSource
Directory(String sourceDirectory, Boolean includeEmptyDirectories, ArtifactPublishOptions 
artifactPublishOptions)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.TargetBlockExtensions.PostAllToUnboundedAndCompleteAsync
[T](ITargetBlock`1 targetBlock, IEnumerable`1 inputs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFiles(String 
sourceDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, IEnumerable`1 pages, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 
hashCompleteCallback)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.PublishAsync(String 
fullPath, ArtifactPublishOptions artifactPublishOptions, String manifestFileOutputPath, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.UPackClientShared.UPackSharedClient.PushWithoutCheckingForDup
licatePackageAsync(String projectNameOrId, String feedNameOrId, String packageName, String packageVersion, 
String description, String sourceDirectory, Boolean honorIgnoreOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.UPackClientShared.UPackSharedClient.PushAsync(String 
projectNameOrId, String feedNameOrId, String packageName, String packageVersion, String description, String 
sourceDirectory, Boolean honorIgnoreOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in 
D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackPublishCommand.cs:line 59
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPack.UPackExceptionMapper.WithExceptionHandlingAsync(Func`1 act) in 
D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackExceptionMapper.cs:line 39
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand.ExecuteAsync() in 
D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackPublishCommand.cs:line 63
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.CommandBase.OnExecuteAsync() in 
D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\CommandBase.cs:line 105
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo 
method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in 
C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext 
context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b
__0>d.MoveNext() in 
C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() 
in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in 
C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 611
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) 
in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 57
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext 
context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, 
String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 
130
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](String[] args) in 
C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 112
```

I can't seem get past to this. I've already tried to `setProfileEnvironment` to true from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config but still error persist. Can you suggest something that I can try to setup in my local machine?

I'm following trying setup in Azure DevOps from this article https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-run-owasp-zap-security-tests-part-of-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline-484da8793a12

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running powershell as administrator?

Comment: `Content.IE5` is a junction (reparse point) and links to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE`.

Comment: What is your CLI version/?

Comment: I'm running PowerShell Admin, with azure cli version 2.15.1.*

Answer (score 0):

Note below points:

1. Run this command in Admin mode.
2. This extension requires CLI 2.2.0 or higher.
3. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_artifacts_universal_publish) doc for it's appropriate usage.

Comment: I'm running PowerShell Admin, with azure cli version 2.15.1.* still issue exists